How to Automatically Add and Update a createdBy Attribute in Every Entity Using NestJS and TypeORM
I'm developing a NestJS application and using TypeORM for database interactions. Each entity in my application already has createdAt and updatedAt attributes, which are automatically managed by TypeORM decorators. I want to add a createdBy attribute to track which user created or last edited each entity.
Here’s an example of my current entity:
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class ExampleEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  createdBy: string;
}

I have an AuthGuard that attaches the user's email to the request object, making it accessible via request.user:
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    request.user = { email: 'user@example.com' };
    return true;
  }
}


To achieve what you described, first, let's define a base entity:
@Entity()
export class BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  createdBy?: string;
}

Then, you can extend all related data entities from the base entity.
Next, choose a mapper to map the data from DTO to your entity. Depending on the chosen mapper, define a mapping between the user property in the DTO to the createdBy in the Entity.

Are you saying we always have to pass the createdBy data from controllers to the repository?
